“Top users” and “Learn more ...” pages are empty
Clicking on “Top users” or “Learn more ...” in the question list for a tag displays an empty page.
This happens

on multiple sites (for example on Meta Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, Mathematics Stack Exchange),
with all tags,
on different operating systems and browsers (tested with Edge on Windows 11, Safari/Firefox/Chrome on macOS 14.5 Sonoma, Mobile Safari on iOS 17.5.1)


Right now it works again!

Sorry about that. We deployed a change to rendering user cards that contained a bug that seems obvious in hindsight but went unnoticed. On the upside, at least question pages were still working. 
The issue has been fixed and all pages rendering user information should be working as normal.

Here's something else that's very likely also related. When clicking on the "helpful flags" link on my status pages' Activity tab (confirmed with this site, Math's main & meta sites, and MathOverflow), I also get an empty page. I only tried using Edge on Windows 10, but I suspect this is very likely due to a problem on the server end and, thus, doesn't have anything to do with the browser or operating system being used.
Interestingly, the flags information screen does work somewhat (in particular, it shows just part of the list of flags on the LHS (I estimate about 2/3 of the page), but not the summary on the RHS) with my main Stack Overflow account. I haven't tried checking any other sites to determine which ones work at least partially and which ones don't work at all, but this shows the issue is at least somewhat site specific.

Yes, I observed the same with the flags page. But right now everything seems to work again.

@MartinR Thanks for the update. What you reported on, and also the flags screens, are also all now working for me as well.
